# SELECT INTO OUTFILE - Can't create/write to file

Tags: mysql, freebsd, select-into-outfile

This query:

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE '/usr/services/001/tmp/`database4ed78d1eb0986`.`tblTemporaryReportFinishedOrders`.tmp';
```

Produces this error:

```
Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file '/usr/services/001/tmp/`database4ed78d1eb0986`.`tblTemporaryReportFinishedOrders`.tmp' (Errcode: 2)
```

The /usr/services/001/tmp has 777 permissions so why does it still not work?

I am using FreeBSD OS.

Comment: Try removing the backquotes from the output filename `/usr/services/001/tmp/database4ed78d1eb0986.tblTemporaryReportFinishedOrders.tmp`

Comment: Try taking out the backticks in the filename. `.../001/tmp/database4ed78d1eb0986.tblTemporaryReportFinishedOrders.tmp`

Comment: @Michael: Great minds think alike?

Comment: @Michael that is not the problem.

Comment: @Richard: What about 001? MySQL has to have access rights to ALL of the directories in the path, though only needs write permissions on the `tmp` subdir. Does that file exist already? MySQL will **NOT** select into a file that already exists as a security precaution.

Comment: Did you grant `file` privilege to your db user?

Answer (score 1):

File names can't contain those back tics. Try with a valid file name.